# How to POST input type date to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm having trouble posting date value from MVC Razor view to MVC Controller

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MainframeFilingDetail", "Report", FormMethod.Post,     htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-inline", id = "formDetails" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="ReportBeginDate">Report Begin Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="BeginDate" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"/>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="ReportEndDate">Report End Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="EndDate"  value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"/>
    </div>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>
```

}

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MainframeFilingDetail(DateTime beginDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var isValidDate = ValidateDate(beginDate, endDate);
    if(!isValidDate)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Date!");
    }

    var mainframeData = GetMainframeData();


    return View(mainframeData);
}
```

**Question**

When I click the submit button I get exception although I have default value in date input type. I cannot have null values passed to the controller.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'beginDate' of       non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult MainframeFilingDetail(System.DateTime,
>   System.DateTime)' in
>   'SOS.BusinessFilings.Web.Int.Controllers.ReportController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Because your inputs do not have `name` attributes so do not post back anything (change `id="BeginDate"` to `name="BeginDate"` etc). But this is an awful way to generate your view. Use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` method to generate the correct html and bind to a model

Comment: @StephenMuecke adding name did work. Thanks!, can you show a snippet for strongly typed HtmlHelper? I don't want to add dates to the Model, they are just used as filters

Comment: Your editing data. **ALWAYS** use a view model and that view model will contain those properties with the appropriate validation attributes and in the view `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BeginDate) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BeginDate) @Html.ValidationMesageFor(m => m.BeginDate)` (and look a what happens when you return the view with your current code - all the data the user entered is lost!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I designed my ViewModel to match the items in the grid, and the Model for view is an IEnumerable collection of ViewModel items. I understand your point, but if I add Date to ViewModel, it will be a collection of Dates. However, date is a input field not a server data

Comment: Your view model would contains properties for the 2 `DateTime` and a property for the collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you that sounds great!, I will take that approach, so I will need another class to define my item in grid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136006/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-billboard).

Answer (score 0):

What I did (and worked well) was to parse the date into timestamp format (13 digits that represent a date). Then, sent it as a string (.toString()) and it solved the problem.

Comment: You can improve your answer by including a code example of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth (and I'm a newbie, so just hoping this helps someone).
I'm working in Visual Studio with an MVC web site and using razor and c# and HTML 5

I had a heck of a time getting a date input element working correctly.
I needed to display the date that got passed into the view via the model, and return the date if it was entered/modified by the user.  On top of that, the date was part of a List property.  Additonally it was defined as a nullabel DateTime  (DateTime?)

Here's the part of the view code that finally enabled me to not only display the passed-in date, but also to correctly post the dates to the next controller action:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CurrentRoles.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentRoles[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentRoles[i].Name)
            @Model.CurrentRoles[i].Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @{ string sdateValue = Model.CurrentRoles[i].StartDate == null ? "" : ((DateTime)(Model.CurrentRoles[i].StartDate)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
            <input type="date" name="CurrentRoles[@i].StartDate" value="@sdateValue" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @{ string edateValue = Model.CurrentRoles[i].EndDate == null ? "" : ((DateTime)(Model.CurrentRoles[i].EndDate)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
            <input type="date" name="CurrentRoles[@i].EndDate" value="@edateValue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```